# Why do we have to declare method as static for recursive call in java?

Tags: java, recursion, static

Can anyone tell me why method should be static for recursive call in Java?

```
class abc {
    static void fun(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.println(n);
            fun(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 3;
        fun(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't.  This is just a shortcut in a toy program to be able to invoke the method directly from `main()` without having to instantiate anything.  `static` is totally unrelated to recursive-ness.

Comment: A method doesn't need to be declared as static in order for it to be used for recursion...you can have a non-static recursive method.

Comment: A method calling itself recursively is no different from that method calling any other method in terms of what is allowed. Note that, if you remove the static, it is the call in `main` which is not allowed, not the recursive call in `fun`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they shouldn't. The reason why you probably it is the case is simply because you started calling your method from a static method which is the `main`, and perhaps started fixing an error after the other.

The `main` is static and hence can't assume a `this` reference implicitly. An alternative "non-static" of writing this would be

```
class abc {
   void fun(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
        fun(n - 1);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 3;
    abc a = new abc();
    a.fun(x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to have the recursive function static. Most of the tutorials keep this as static so that it is easy for them to demonstrate it's usage without creating a new instance of the class in which recursive function is defined.

If it is a non-static recursive function then a new instance needs to be created to call the function. Whereas a static function can be accessed by the class itself without creating an instance of the same.

A simple example of a recursive function to find factorial is as below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Main().getFactorial(5));
    }

    public int getFactorial(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return n * getFactorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question makes sense from a good Class Design Guideline perspective, It should have to be static because lets see the factorial(int n) method for computing the factorial n, it should be defined static because it is independent of any specific instance. It is a common design error to define an instance method that should have been static.
If a method does not depend on a specific instance it should be a static method.
Reference: Introduction to Java Programming, by Daniel Liang